# VPN on cloud - IP cameras

Tags: networking, vpn, ip, local-area-network, cloud

Is it possible to have VPN for example on OceanCloud or AWS and make it work as local VPN?

I have 3 security cameras on 3 different lacations which doesn't have public IP adresses and one NAS server on different location too, client is somewhere else also. Is there a possible way to connect all of these to "LAN"?

It would be easy if the camera was on LAN with VPN but i have no idea how would this behave on cloud.

Thank you for answers.

EDIT : I added diagram, for better understanding, how I imagine it to work. https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uw4pD.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would require a vpn-client at each site, which acts as (vpn) router. Maybe if your IP-camera supports VPN' (don't know any which do). Otherwise you'd need a server/router on each site (a Raspberry Pi is more than sufficient).

Learn how networking works. And read the [OpenVPN Howto](https://openvpn.net/index.php/open-source/documentation/howto.html), which is nicely written in my opinion. First try to 'tun' each location. Afterwards add routing to the LAN segments. Use `route ..` (in the openvpn server.conf) to make OpenVPN accept the traffic, and `push "route .."` so the client knows where to find each camera.

I don't want to depend inward (NAT) routing, so my VPN-servers are located in the Cloud. I'm using 4 servers (VPS') at different datacenters. Each client has 4 VPN's (and `bird`), which gives me ECMP routing between all clients.

On my LAN segment sit a few devices, none of them serves services on the LAN and they only accept traffic from the VPN. It might be a bit overkill, but this way I don't depend static IP's (can very easily switch from ISP).